# Razor action link: append parameter to current url

Tags: razor

I have the following current url: `www.mysite.com/Search/SearchForJobs?JobTitle=it&JobLocation=wien`

I want to append the parameter `&Page=2`.

Is this possible with an action link or an route link?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that adds a parameter to any url

```
public static string AddParameterToUrl(string url, string parameterName, string parameterValue)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string queryStringValue = "";
    int startIndex = url.IndexOf("?");

    if (startIndex >= 0)
    {
      queryStringValue = url.Substring(startIndex);
      url = url.Substring(0, startIndex);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterName))
    {
        queryStringValue = AddUrlParameter(queryStringValue, parameterName.ToLower(), parameterValue);
    }

    return (url + queryStringValue);
}
```

Comment: There must be a better way!?